# Why can't I have a folder named the same as a LINQ to SQL class

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I'm using the LINQ to SQL dbml with a table/class named `Category`. If I make a folder in the project named Category I can no longer reference the table `Category` in my code. Why is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because adding the folder creates a namespace with it.
ie.
MyProject.Category will then refer the the linq to sql class as well as the namespace of your new folder.

This is probably bad practive to have a class and namespace called the same thing (especially if they are both in the same parent namespace)

Comment: So I just need to name the folder something else then?